# Visualising LiDAR data in 3D as ArcGIS Service in browser with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, 3d, lidar

I have lidar data which I would like to present over the intranet in 3D. I have arcgis server 10.3.1 with the image extention. I am however not sure if such a service is available.

Is this possible?

As far as I can see this is only available online through webscenes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Lidar data in ArcGIS Online you will need to package the data into a scene layer package and upload it to ArcGIS Online creating a point cloud scene layer.

This support for this type of scene layer is coming in Portal 10.5.1 and will follow a similar workflow with uploading and publishing a scene layer from a scene layer package.

Comment: Can you expand your answer with more details; i.e, show how it can be done? Perhaps using some screenshots?